# In Vtiger database where can i find the relation between tables vtiger_users and vtiger_contactdetails?

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I want to know contact's owner with a MySQL query.

I'm using Vtiger 7.1 with PHP 7 and MySQL 5.

Answer (score 0):

The owner information is stored in the **smownerid** column of the **vtiger_crmentity** table. The **contactid** column for **vtiger_contactdetails** table is a foreign key for the **crmid** column in the **vtiger_crmentity** table.

For example, given a contact with record id = 1000, you will use the query as -

```
select * from vtiger_users where id=(select smownerid from vtiger_crmentity where crmid=1000)
```

Comment: Great, that's it. Thanks